# Is UTF-8 sensitive to byte order?

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, uuid, endianness

So I need to generate a UUID with a string as the input to a hash function.

As I understand it MS's implementation of GUID is not endian portable and therefore does not implement RFC 4122 correctly. So I am wondering if I am falling in basically the same pitfall by passing the .NET System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(data) function a UTF-8 string.

I believe I am fine as wikipedia seems to indicate that byte order doesn't matter for UTF-8 and the Byte Order Mark is essentially demoted to being a header to denote that the string is in UTF-8.

Edit: Note I am trying to use a UTF-8 string as a seed for the hash used in the UUID.

Comment: You cannot parse arbitrary bytes as UTF8.

Comment: I'm using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

Comment: @cb88, Just try `byte[] b1 = new byte[] { 255, 255 }; byte[] b2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b1));`. `b1` will not be equal to `b2`

Comment: @cb88 see *SLaks*' comment. For conversion between arbitrary byte array and strings, you can use   `Convert.ToBase64String` `Convert.FromBase64String`

Comment: @cb88 because he is trying to decode invalid UTF-8, which by default doesn't throw an exception but uses replacement strategy instead, resulting in a string `"��"`. And when he encodes `"��"` as UTF-8, the result is a byte array `{239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189}`. I think he is trying to say that you cannot decode random bytes as UTF-8. This will be more apparent when you use exception strategy for decoding.

Comment: I think all the commenters here are missing the point of the question. The question is: can a little endian or big endian machine encode the same sequence of unicode codepoints to a different byte sequence? I.e., does the UTF-8 BOM actually define the byte order used in the encoded data or is BOM a misnomer? If a particular string *always* has the exact byte-per-byte representation in UTF-8, then you can treat the UTF-8 encoded `byte[]` as a platform-independent key/get the same hash value. If you can’t make that assumption, you’d need to force the UTF-8 encoder to use a particular endianness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF8 does not have multiple byte orders.
Instead, the UTF8 specification precisely defines the byte order used to encode non-ASCII characters.

However, you cannot parse an arbitrary hash as UTF8.

Comment: Would that mean that UTF-8 could define the byte order differently on different systems therefore meaning that I might not always be able to regenerate the correct UUID from the seed string? I suppose it should be possible to convert to ASCII to avoid that.

Comment: @cb88: No.  UTF-8 is a _standard_.  Any system that defines UTF8 differently is evil and broken and not actually using UTF8.

Comment: Just as a side note UUID _fields_ are big endian per field. IE the entire UUID is not converted to big endian but each field individually. Of course that makes perfect sence except that isn't what occured to me initially since it isn't straight forward.

Answer (score 7):

Arrays of bytes do not have an endian problem.  Everybody agrees that the first element in the array has the lowest address, regardless of the machine architecture.  A Guid is not an array of bytes, it is a struct that has fields that are not a byte.  And is thus sensitive to endian order.

A utf-8 encoded string is a byte[].  ComputeHash() takes a byte[].  They are therefore not sensitive to endianness.

Comment: But is it possible for a little-endian and big-endian machine to encode the same unicode characters to a different byte[] sequence when encoding to UTF-8 or is the UTF-8 BOM not actually a BOM (byte order mark)?

Comment: Nothing to do with byte order.  How useful it is depends on who you talk to.  A Windows programmer will insist that a utf-8 encoded text file has a BOM so he can distinguish it from a legacy codepage encoded file.  A Unix programmer will insist that it doesn't because it screws up his shell's sigil detection.